# BeautifulSoup Returns empty list which leads to an IndexError in my Python code

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to do web scraping using BeautifulSoup. The code I have written is below:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

questions = soup.select(".question-summary")
print(type(questions[0]))
```

When I run the code, I get the error message below:

```
print(type(questions[10]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Then i tried to print the list like below:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

questions = soup.select(".question-summary")
print(questions)
```

And then I get an empty list: []

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.question-summary` is incorrect locator because it's a portion of `id` meaning each `id value` start with `question-summary`. Now it's working.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

questions = soup.select('[id^="question-summary"]')
print(questions)
```

Output:

```
1" data-post-type-id="1" id="question-summary-71715531">
<div class="s-post-summary--stats js-post-summary-stats">
<div class="s-post-summary--stats-item s-post-summary--stats-item__emphasized" title="Score of 0">
<span class="s-post-summary--stats-item-number">0</span>
<span class="s-post-summary--stats-item-unit">votes</span>
</div>
<div class="s-post-summary--stats-item" title="0 answers">
<span class="s-post-summary--stats-item-number">0</span>
<span class="s-post-summary--stats-item-unit">answers</span>
</div>
<div class="s-post-summary--stats-item" title="5 views">
<span class="s-post-summary--stats-item-number">5</span>
<span class="s-post-summary--stats-item-unit">views</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="s-post-summary--content">
<h3 class="s-post-summary--content-title">
<a class="s-link" href="/questions/71715531/is-it-possible-to-draw-a-logistic-regression-graph-with-multiple-x-variable">Is it possible to draw a 
logistic regression graph with multiple x variable?</a>
</h3>
<div class="s-post-summary--content-excerpt">
                Currently, this is my X and V value. May I know is it possible to draw a logistic regression curve with X that has multiple column? Or I am required to draw multiple graphs to do so?
X = df1.drop(['...
            </div>
<div class="s-post-summary--meta">
<div class="s-post-summary--meta-tags tags js-tags t-python-3ûx t-machine-learning">
<a class="post-tag flex--item mt0 js-tagname-python-3ûx" href="/questions/tagged/python-3.x" rel="tag" title="show questions tagged 'python-3.x'">python-3.x</a> <a class="post-tag flex--item mt0 js-tagname-machine-learning" href="/questions/tagged/machine-learning" rel="tag" title="show questions tagged 'machine-learning'">machine-learning</a>
</div>
<div class="s-user-card s-user-card__minimal">
<a class="s-avatar s-avatar__16 s-user-card--avatar" href="/users/14128881/christopher-chua"> <div class="gravatar-wrapper-16" data-user-id="14128881">
<img ,="" alt="user avatar" class="s-avatar--image" height="16" src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Sn3B_E5hiJc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMZuucl1oyfdhJiXhrx73JLYqzKAK9icag/photo.jpg?sz=32" width="16"/>
</div>
</a>
<div class="s-user-card--info">
<div class="s-user-card--link d-flex gs4">
<a class="flex--item" href="/users/14128881/christopher-chua">Christopher Chua</a>
</div>
<ul class="s-user-card--awards">
<li class="s-user-card--rep"><span class="todo-no-class-here" dir="ltr" title="reputation score ">7</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
<time class="s-user-card--time">asked <span class="relativetime" title="2022-04-02 07:03:06Z">13 mins ago</span></time>
```

.. so on

Comment: It works now. Was a mistake on my part. I did not add the "^" after "id ". Thanks a lot.